# Why am I receiving undefined in this example of higher order functions?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am trying to come up with a simple example of how higher order functions work, and for some reason I'm getting undefined when I run this code. I've been staring at it for an hour and hitting a wall. Is there a return statement I'm missing somewhere? Thanks in advance.

```
var result = 0;
var nums = [1,2,3,4];
var square = function(number) { 
  result = number * number;
  return result;
}

function each(array, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    func(array[i]);
  }
}


function sumSquares(arrayOfNumbers) {
  return each(arrayOfNumbers, square);
}
```

Comment: each doesnt return anything

Answer (score 0):

The `func(array[i]);` expression is going unused. You want to *sum up* each return value, so you can `return` a call of `reduce`:

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,4];
var square = function(sumSoFar, number) { 
  return sumSoFar + number * number;
}

function each(array, func) {
  return array.reduce(func, 0);
}


function sumSquares(arrayOfNumbers) {
  return each(arrayOfNumbers, square);
}
console.log(sumSquares(nums));
```

Array methods really are the way to go when possible, but if that's forbidden for some reason, then manually add the call of `func` with the `result` inside of `each`:

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,4];
var square = function(number) { 
  result = number * number;
  return result;
}

function each(array, func) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += func(array[i]);
  }
  return result;
}


function sumSquares(arrayOfNumbers) {
  return each(arrayOfNumbers, square);
}
console.log(sumSquares(nums));
```

Comment: considering they arent using map or  forEach either I dont think its intended to use array methods